# Find a cartesian equation corresponding to the parametric equations

Tags: calculus, parametrization

Find a Cartesian equation relating x and y corresponding to the parametric equations
$x=3\sin(6t)$, $y=6\cos(6t)$.

Write your answer in the form *P(x,y)=0*
where P(x,y) is a polynomial in x and y such that the coefficient of $y^2$ is 9.

Attempt:

This seems a difficult problem, since we don't know how x and y are related. First, knowing the identity $\sin t=\cos(t+\frac{\pi}{2})$, I attempted the following

$$x+y=3\sin(6t)+6\sin((6+2\pi)t$$

But then, the coefficient of $y$ is 1. So trying:

$$x+9y^2=3\sin(6t)+9(6\sin((6+2\pi)t)^2$$

But from here I am stuck.

Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: **HINT:** Calculate $x^2+\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2$. What do you get?

Comment: I tried $x^2+9x^2$ before, but got nothing of relevance. Then I tried your suggestion and got $9\sin^26t+3\cos^26t$

Comment: Luthier, I said $(y/2)^2$, **not** $y^2/2$.

Comment: right $9\sin^26t+9\cos^2(6t)$. What is your motive to select that combination?

Comment: Ok, and now remember some trigonometry. $\sin^2+\cos^2=???$

Comment: Yes,  $cos^2x+sin^2x=1$

Comment: That's enough to solve the question.

Comment: Thanks, I see now..

Comment: Consider initial equations as $x=3\cos(6t) ; y=\color{red}{2 \times} 3\sin(6t)$. You could have guessed that it is an **ellipse** because these equations can be read as "elongating a circle with radius $3$, by a factor $\color{red}{2}$ in the direction of $y$ axis".